# VBA Timer Using Do Loop

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a countdown in VBA, that displays the seconds in a textbox1. I am using this code below,  but nothing happens and the textbox doesn't increment each second. I have tried doing Endtick / 1000 too because it's ms, but to still now avail. Is this the right method I should be using?

Other stuff is happening in the app as the timer is running, so I can't use the WAIT function.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    timer (10)
End Sub




Sub timer(Finish As Long)
 
    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long
 
    EndTick = GetTickCount + (Finish * 1000)
     
    Do
 
        NowTick = GetTickCount
        DoEvents
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = GetTickCount
        
 
    Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
    msgbox("Time is up")
 
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me -- IF you put the `timer` sub in a module and not in with the user form. What is shown in the textbox is not counting down, however. It shows the `Long` count of milliseconds from `GetTickCount`.  So you'll have to capture the tick count at the start, then make it decrement as you go along.

Comment: Hi, I tried it in a module, howevever no message is popping up at the end... nothing seems to show in my textbox at all, although it looks like its trying as I cant type in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to a module, separate from the userform code:

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#End If

Sub timer(Finish As Long)
    Dim EndTick As Long
    EndTick = GetTickCount + (Finish * 1000)
    Do
        DoEvents
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = (EndTick - GetTickCount) / 1000
    Loop Until GetTickCount >= EndTick
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = 0
    MsgBox ("Time is up")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peter,  that did exactly what I wanted - above and beyond. I was missing the libs . thank you for taking the time, it is very much appreciated.